# Bayesian network for classification using PyMc or PyMc3

Tags: bayesian-networks

I am seraching for a  while  an example  on how to use  PyMc/PyMc3 to do  classification task, but have not  found  an concludent   example  regarding  on how to do   the  predicton on a  new data point.
I am currious if some   could   give  me some references.

Comment: Will be easier to help you if you post some code, maybe some toy-model

Answer (score 2):

`pymc` will not provide you pretty sklearn-style `.predict` method for this case, however you can do it on your own. The idea is simple enough: you should draw coefficients for the classifier using pymc, and after it use them for the classifier itself manually.

You can see a very basic example at [this blogpost](https://healthyalgorithms.com/2012/03/05/mcmc-in-python-a-random-effects-logistic-regression-example/) or more complicated case at [pymc3 documentation](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/GLM-logistic.html).

Comment: Please make sure you're including the answer itself in your post, rather than a link to the answer. (I don't know enough about the subject to say whether or not you are, but in case you're not, I want to mention it)